# Converting html to cshtml file

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a html file and I want to convert it into .cshtml file.

Can any one help me in this?

Please find my html code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">



  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/assets/css/docs.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>
    #content {
      background:#0074d9;
      background:linear-gradient(135deg, #0074d9, #001f3f);
    }
  </style>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.3.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/assets/js/docs.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<section class="bs-docs-section clearfix">
  <h1 id="import_export" class="page-header">
    Import/Export
  </h1>

  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
    <div id="builder-import_export"></div>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-warning reset" data-target="import_export">Reset</button>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary parse-sql" data-target="import_export" data-stmt="false">SQL</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<link href="http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/seiyria-bootstrap-slider/dist/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/selectize/dist/css/selectize.default.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/css/query-builder.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/momentjs/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/seiyria-bootstrap-slider/dist/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/selectize/dist/js/standalone/selectize.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/js/query-builder.standalone.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/sql-parser/browser/sql-parser.js"></script>

<script>var baseurl = 'http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder';</script>
<script src="http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/assets/demo-basic.js"></script>
<script src="http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/assets/demo-widgets.js"></script>
<script src="http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/assets/demo-plugins.js"></script>
<script src="http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/assets/demo-import-export.js"></script>
<script src="http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/assets/demo.js"></script>

<style>
.code-popup { max-height:500px; }
</style>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3" role="complementary">
        <div class="bs-docs-sidebar hidden-print">


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trianglify/0.1.2/trianglify.min.js"></script>
  <script>trianglify('#0074d9', '#001f3f');</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to change this to .cshtml file so that I can use it in ASP.NET MVC application.

Answer (score 0):

You directly copy this HTML content in CSHTML page it will works fine.

Razor syntax is apply in cshtml for your textbox, dropdown, listbox ..  type of razor controllers other code remain same as HTML code.

Comment: when I run the html file it works fine and it returns the value but when I copy and pasted the code in cshtml file it works i.e., control appears(this is the code for jquery-querybuilder plugin) but some functions are not working